# Simple Alarm Clock in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, alarm, alarms

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to develop a simple Alarm Clock in Rails 4. Basically you should be able to set the time of the alarm. On the index page (main page) you will see "number 5" image that will gradually change to "4", "3", "2" and "1" approaching the time when it is supposed to go off. "Number 1" will appear at the time when the alarm goes off.

So far I've created scaffold:
rails g scaffold Alarmclock alarm:time

I've added the "5" image to the index file by using an image for from a website: http://clareluffman.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/red-number-5.jpg

I'm assuming that the Alarmclock Controller should look something this :

```
 def index
   @alarmclocks = Alarmclock.all
   @alarm_goes_off = Alarmclock.where(Time.now == [:alarm])
 end
```

And the index.html.erb should have some if "alarm_goes_off" statements.... if this happens, display image "5". if this happens, display "4". Also, the page should be refreshing by itself. So I probably required some kind of cron job.

It's all in my head but I'm not sure how I should implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need client side code, javascript, to be able to do what you want... It needs to watch the time to go off... and update the page with AJAX...

```
@alarm_goes_off = Alarmclock.where(Time.now == [:alarm])
```

This line of code is going to do nothing for you... as it's very unlikely that your page is ever going to be loaded at the exact time of your alarm... to the micro second. Hence it's almost always going to be Nil.

Comment: Thanks... I've found some Javascript code: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/alarm.shtml